# After mongodb update mongodb won't to strart on centos 7

Tags: linux, mongodb, server, centos, centos7

I updated my server but the mongodb server stopped and don't wont to start.
there is the log of `systemctl status mongod.service`:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since ر 2021-07-14 13:13:49 CEST; 19s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 7554 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=14)
  Process: 7551 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7548 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7546 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

يول 14 13:13:49 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
يول 14 13:13:49 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[7554]: about to fork child process, waiting....
يول 14 13:13:49 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[7554]: forked process: 7557
يول 14 13:13:49 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[7554]: ERROR: child process failed, exited ...4
يول 14 13:13:49 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[7554]: To see additional information in thi....
يول 14 13:13:49 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exite...14
يول 14 13:13:49 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
يول 14 13:13:49 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
يول 14 13:13:49 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

and this is the result of `journalctl -xe`:

```
يول 14 13:15:21 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com su[8069]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user odyssee.admin
يول 14 13:15:21 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of odyssee.admin.
-- Subject: Unit user-1002.slice has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit user-1002.slice has finished shutting down.
يول 14 13:16:46 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com named[974]: network unreachable resolving '57.249.131.104.in-addr.arpa/PTR/IN': 2400:cb00:20
يول 14 13:16:46 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com named[974]: network unreachable resolving '57.249.131.104.in-addr.arpa/PTR/IN': 2400:cb00:20
يول 14 13:16:46 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com named[974]: network unreachable resolving 'ns3.digitalocean.com/A/IN': 2803:f800:50::6ca2:c0
يول 14 13:16:46 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com named[974]: network unreachable resolving 'ns3.digitalocean.com/AAAA/IN': 2803:f800:50::6ca2
يول 14 13:16:46 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com unix_chkpwd[8183]: password check failed for user (root)
يول 14 13:16:46 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8173]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser
يول 14 13:16:46 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8173]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
يول 14 13:16:49 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8203]: Address 222.255.217.139 maps to static.vnpt.vn, but this does not map back to th
يول 14 13:16:49 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com unix_chkpwd[8208]: password check failed for user (root)
يول 14 13:16:49 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8203]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser
يول 14 13:16:49 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8203]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
يول 14 13:16:49 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8173]: Failed password for root from 104.131.249.57 port 60153 ssh2
يول 14 13:16:49 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8173]: Received disconnect from 104.131.249.57 port 60153:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
يول 14 13:16:49 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8173]: Disconnected from 104.131.249.57 port 60153 [preauth]
يول 14 13:16:50 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8203]: Failed password for root from 222.255.217.139 port 26131 ssh2
يول 14 13:16:51 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8203]: Received disconnect from 222.255.217.139 port 26131:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
يول 14 13:16:51 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8203]: Disconnected from 222.255.217.139 port 26131 [preauth]
يول 14 13:16:53 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com unix_chkpwd[8237]: password check failed for user (root)
يول 14 13:16:53 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8233]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser
يول 14 13:16:53 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8233]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
يول 14 13:16:56 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8233]: Failed password for root from 45.119.215.150 port 46894 ssh2
يول 14 13:16:56 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8233]: Received disconnect from 45.119.215.150 port 46894:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
يول 14 13:16:56 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8233]: Disconnected from 45.119.215.150 port 46894 [preauth]
يول 14 13:18:25 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com unix_chkpwd[8488]: password check failed for user (root)
[root@vps1 ~]# clear
[root@vps1 ~]# journalctl -xe
يول 14 13:16:51 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8203]: Disconnected from 222.255.217.139 port 26131 [preauth]
يول 14 13:16:53 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com unix_chkpwd[8237]: password check failed for user (root)
يول 14 13:16:53 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8233]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser
يول 14 13:16:53 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8233]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
يول 14 13:16:56 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8233]: Failed password for root from 45.119.215.150 port 46894 ssh2
يول 14 13:16:56 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8233]: Received disconnect from 45.119.215.150 port 46894:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
يول 14 13:16:56 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8233]: Disconnected from 45.119.215.150 port 46894 [preauth]
يول 14 13:18:25 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com unix_chkpwd[8488]: password check failed for user (root)
يول 14 13:18:25 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8484]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser
يول 14 13:18:25 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8484]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
يول 14 13:18:27 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8484]: Failed password for root from 162.243.18.87 port 41854 ssh2
يول 14 13:18:27 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8484]: Received disconnect from 162.243.18.87 port 41854:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
يول 14 13:18:27 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8484]: Disconnected from 162.243.18.87 port 41854 [preauth]
يول 14 13:18:56 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8515]: Address 222.255.217.139 maps to static.vnpt.vn, but this does not map back to th
يول 14 13:18:56 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com unix_chkpwd[8518]: password check failed for user (root)
يول 14 13:18:56 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8515]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser
يول 14 13:18:56 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8515]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
يول 14 13:18:58 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8515]: Failed password for root from 222.255.217.139 port 15481 ssh2
يول 14 13:18:58 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8515]: Received disconnect from 222.255.217.139 port 15481:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
يول 14 13:18:58 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8515]: Disconnected from 222.255.217.139 port 15481 [preauth]
يول 14 13:19:09 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com unix_chkpwd[8532]: password check failed for user (root)
يول 14 13:19:09 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8529]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser
يول 14 13:19:09 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8529]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
يول 14 13:19:11 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8529]: Failed password for root from 45.119.215.150 port 53724 ssh2
يول 14 13:19:11 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8529]: Received disconnect from 45.119.215.150 port 53724:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
يول 14 13:19:11 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8529]: Disconnected from 45.119.215.150 port 53724 [preauth]
يول 14 13:19:17 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com unix_chkpwd[8542]: password check failed for user (root)
يول 14 13:19:17 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8538]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser
يول 14 13:19:17 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8538]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
يول 14 13:19:19 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8538]: Failed password for root from 104.131.249.57 port 49890 ssh2
يول 14 13:19:19 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8538]: Received disconnect from 104.131.249.57 port 49890:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
يول 14 13:19:19 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sshd[8538]: Disconnected from 104.131.249.57 port 49890 [preauth]
```

`journalctl -xe | grep [Mm]ongo` returns :

```
يول 14 13:41:44 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sudo[13650]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/lib/mongo ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/service mongodb start
يول 14 13:42:25 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sudo[13715]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/lib/mongo ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start mongod
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has begun start-up
-- Unit mongod.service has begun starting up.
يول 14 13:42:26 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[13731]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
يول 14 13:42:26 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[13731]: forked process: 13734
يول 14 13:42:26 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[13731]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with 14
يول 14 13:42:26 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[13731]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
يول 14 13:42:26 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=14
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
-- Unit mongod.service has failed.
يول 14 13:42:26 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
يول 14 13:42:26 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
يول 14 13:44:53 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sudo[13973]:     root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/lib/mongodb ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start mongod
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has begun start-up
-- Unit mongod.service has begun starting up.
يول 14 13:44:53 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[13988]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
يول 14 13:44:53 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[13988]: forked process: 13991
يول 14 13:44:54 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[13988]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with 14
يول 14 13:44:54 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[13988]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
يول 14 13:44:54 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=14
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
-- Unit mongod.service has failed.
يول 14 13:44:54 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
يول 14 13:44:54 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
يول 14 13:45:23 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sudo[14275]:     root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/lib ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start mongod
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has begun start-up
-- Unit mongod.service has begun starting up.
يول 14 13:45:24 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[14294]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
يول 14 13:45:24 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[14294]: forked process: 14298
يول 14 13:45:24 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[14294]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with 14
يول 14 13:45:24 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[14294]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
يول 14 13:45:24 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=14
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
-- Unit mongod.service has failed.
يول 14 13:45:24 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
يول 14 13:45:24 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
يول 14 14:07:23 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sudo[17608]:     root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongo
يول 14 14:07:43 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sudo[17627]:     root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/chown -R mongod:mongod /var/log/mongodb
يول 14 14:07:51 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sudo[17638]:     root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start mongod
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has begun start-up
-- Unit mongod.service has begun starting up.
يول 14 14:07:51 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[17655]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
يول 14 14:07:51 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[17655]: forked process: 17658
يول 14 14:07:52 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[17655]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with 14
يول 14 14:07:52 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[17655]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
يول 14 14:07:52 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=14
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
-- Unit mongod.service has failed.
يول 14 14:07:52 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
يول 14 14:07:52 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
يول 14 14:07:58 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sudo[17669]:     root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl stop mongod
يول 14 14:08:01 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sudo[17680]:     root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start mongod
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has begun start-up
-- Unit mongod.service has begun starting up.
يول 14 14:08:01 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[17696]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
يول 14 14:08:01 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[17696]: forked process: 17699
يول 14 14:08:01 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[17696]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with 14
يول 14 14:08:01 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[17696]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
يول 14 14:08:01 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=14
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
-- Unit mongod.service has failed.
يول 14 14:08:01 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
يول 14 14:08:01 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
يول 14 14:08:35 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sudo[17765]:     root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/service mongodb start
يول 14 14:08:43 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sudo[17831]:     root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start mongod
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has begun start-up
-- Unit mongod.service has begun starting up.
يول 14 14:08:44 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[17847]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
يول 14 14:08:44 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[17847]: forked process: 17850
يول 14 14:08:44 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[17847]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with 14
يول 14 14:08:44 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com mongod[17847]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
يول 14 14:08:44 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=14
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
-- Unit mongod.service has failed.
يول 14 14:08:44 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
يول 14 14:08:44 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
يول 14 14:11:26 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com su[18403]: (to mongod) root on pts/1
يول 14 14:11:26 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com su[18403]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user mongod by root(uid=0)
يول 14 14:11:27 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com su[18403]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user mongod
يول 14 14:13:12 vps1.besthost-tunisie.com sudo[18503]:     root : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/lib ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status mongod
```

this is log file:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T14:08:44.085+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T14:08:44.125+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T14:08:44.126+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T14:08:44.139+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":17850,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongo","architecture":"64-bit","host":"vps1.besthost-tunisie.com"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T14:08:44.139+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.6","gitVersion":"72e66213c2c3eab37d9358d5e78ad7f5c1d0d0d7","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"rhel70","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T14:08:44.139+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)","version":"Kernel 3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T14:08:44.139+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017},"processManagement":{"fork":true,"pidFilePath":"/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid","timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongo","journal":{"enabled":true}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T14:08:44.140+02:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T14:08:44.140+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":919}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-07-14T14:08:44.140+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

How to solve this problem ? i can't start the server or export the database to delete mongodb and reinstall it

Comment: **1.** Run `systemctl status mongod.service -l` instead. 
**2.** Include the output of `journalctl -xe | grep [Mm]ongo` instead. **3.** Also, what was the update 'from to'?

Comment: What do you have in your logfile? (typically `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`)

Comment: i edited the post and i included all what you need thank you

Comment: Remove file `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` - I guess you must try this as root user.

Comment: for the version i forgot the version but now i'm on version 4.4.6

Comment: Did you try to update mongo without stopping the service beforehand?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes that's what i did